# Getting wrong values with OLEDB select statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, visual-c++, oledb

I'm running Oracle 11g2 32b locally and I'm connecting to it in code. I use VC++ and connect with OLE DB.  The connection is working fine (finally) and I can insert data into my table without problem.

Where I do run into problems, however, is when fetching data.  I have a single table called ITEM just to test my stuff on.  I use a CCommand.  The command executes and my command actually contains data. In fact, it contains the correct amount of columns and rows; however, it doesn't seem to contain the correct data.

When I run this, I should get 7 rows numbered 4 to 10, while I instead receive progressively increasing and distant values between 83 000 000 and 168 000 000. When I try to obtain the column names I also get numbers instead of strings.

```
stringstream stream;
    string str;
    stream << "SELECT * FROM ITEM";
    str = stream.str();
    wstring commandText = s2ws(str);

    hr = cmd.Open(session, commandText.c_str());
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        cout << "Select failed." << endl; 
        //Cropped for brevity, closes connection and returns -1
    }else{
        cout << "Selection successful." << endl;
        hr = cmd.MoveFirst();
        int counter = 0;
        while(!FAILED(hr) && hr != DB_S_ENDOFROWSET){
            counter++;
            hr = cmd.MoveNext();
            cout << *(long*)(cmd.GetValue(1)) << endl;
        }
        cout << "Number of entries : " << counter << endl;
    }
```

I first though it might be a Data Type problem (my column's data type in Oracle is INTEGER), so I tried different types instead of "long", but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I was able to retrieve a VARCHAR on another test table, but I am still struggling with numerics.

EDIT: Further testing showed that 4 different numeric DBTYPEs all read different outrageous numbers.

EDIT: I was able to read the numbers as strings and convert them back to int in my code.  This is completely ridiculous, but it works.  I would still like to know the proper way of doing it if someone figures something out, but until then, this is going to have to do.

Comment: Being Oracle... have you even tried using an Oracle client provider insead of OleDb provider?

Comment: You should post here `descr your_table`. In your code you cast numbers to `long` (to content of long*), but, how are this numbers stored indatabase? What is `typeof(cmd.GetValue(1))` ? Why do you don't cout directly cmd.GetValue(1): `cout << *cmd.GetValue(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are running into an endian problem with your cast. Try using the templated (see [CDynamicAccessor::GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbtfwae7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) form of GetValue to get numerics.